# How to create an Emgu::CV::Image with a specific type?

Tags: opencv, c++-cli, emgucv

In OpenCV we have access to the CV_XX types which allow you to create a matrix with, for example, CV_32SC1. How do I do this in EmguCV?

The reason for asking is:

I am currently using EmguCV and getting an error where I need to create a specific type of Image and am unable to find those values.

Here is my code:

```
Emgu::CV::Image<Emgu::CV::Structure::Gray, byte>^ mask = gcnew Emgu::CV::Image<Emgu::CV::Structure::Gray, byte>(gray->Size);
try { CvInvoke::cvDistTransform(255-gray, tmp, CvEnum::DIST_TYPE::CV_DIST_L1, 3, nullptr, mask); }
```

Which gives the error:

> OpenCV: the output array of labels must be 32sC1

So I believe I need to change the byte type to 32sC1, how do I do this?

I am using EmguCV 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Working with images](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images) page, specifically the section on EmguCV 2.0, it provides the following clarification on image depth:

> Image Depth Image Depth is specified using the second generic
>   parameter Depth. The types of depth supported in Emgu CV 1.4.0.0
>   include
>
> - Byte
> - SByte
> - Single (float)
> - Double
> - UInt16
> - Int16
> - Int32 (int)

I believe this means it does not use the CV_XXX types at all and only the above.

For my issue i set the type to Int32 and it seemed to stop erroring.